# Struts2 - Implementing ModelDriven - Create an interceptor that accesses the model properties

Tags: struts2, interceptor, model-driven, model-driven-development

I'm relatively new to Struts2.
I've started using ModelDriven to reduce overhead in development.
I wanted to write an interface to modify a property before it gets to the action but I don't see how you can access the properties of a class that implements ModelDriven for the Model.

I can see how things like validate() can work as they are in the actual action class. 
I changed the design to encapsulate the logic behind the service anyways but still would like to know if this is possible.

We're doing everything by ajax/json so I find modeldriven helps quite a lot - not sure if there is a better alternative though!

Edit - code example:

Trying to replace a message with a message in a template to use in an email body.

```
public class EmailActionImpl implements EmailAction {

private Email email=new Email();    
private EmailService emailService;

public Email getModel(){
    return email;
}
[... getters and setters ...]

    public String execute(){
    logger.info("Email action is sendind an email...");

    try{
        emailService.sendNewMail(email);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Email not sent: " + e.getMessage());
        return "failure";
    }   
    return "success";
}
}
```

Email model something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="email")
public class Email {
private Long id;
private String from;
private String to;
private String message;
private String templateType;
 [...]
 }
```

I would like an interceptor preprocessor to replace email.message.
Should look something like this but action.getMessage/setMessage aren't available.

```
public class SimpleInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
   EmailAction action = (EmailAction)invocation.getAction();
   action.setMessage(MessageTemplateFactoryImpl(action.getMessage(), action.getTemplateType());
   return invocation.invoke();
}
}
```

Comment: if i understand it right you want to modify the property being set from the form?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Without knowing that it is hard to say.  You could modify the values in the request, but it would generally make more sense to implement your own type converter. Both of these cover a number of cases and avoid inspecting the action and directly setting values with your own interceptor.

Comment: I'll post code examples shortly.

Comment: Consider grouping actions into the same class when using ajax. With a nice service layer, someone visiting that class will see the variations all in one place and know all the features offered. Also unless the model is used in its entirety by all the ajax actions it can raise more questions. Such as: If, I am adding a new feature, does it already exist? The model tells you what is possible (by asking "given the db and this data what questions can be answered?") but only the actions tell you what has been implemented, and putting all actions in the same place then is good self documentation.

Comment: Okay I agree. In the case of what I implemented previous to this, modeldriven was perfect but in this case I don't believe this is the right way to do things. It seems Model driven is good strictly for adding persistence to a client side function. For any backend function it is better to do everything through a service layer.

Comment: @JasonG: In addition to what Quaternion said interceptors are not the place what you trying to do and Interceptors will be shares among the Actions and which leads to the issue of thread safety.

Comment: If you do not need this question answered please close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to implement an interceptor to work on a particular set of models then you will check if the Action implements ModelDriven. Via reflection (or Apache bean utils) you can derive the particular model in question, to determine if your interceptor applies and then act on it accordingly.

Comment: Great - true - reflection. Just learned this concept yesterday. This would be a fun experiment.